# how to add a users input in javascript into html

Tags: javascript, html

OK so i'm programming a text based game but i would like to have the user input his name with java script

var name = prompt('Whats your name traveler');

then when i write a paragraph in html would like to put the users name in there I've searched around, but couldn't find anything i'm new to programming and this is my first game please help.

Comment: You've searched around and couldn't find **anything**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create p tag with any unique id and if user entered data is not null then put the content in p tag like this

```js
var name = prompt('Whats your name traveler');

if(name !== null)
{
  $('#user').text(name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="user" ></p>
```

Comment: I think `if(name)` is enough to validate . instead of `if(name !== null)`

Answer (score 0):

Get the element by using relevant selector,like in this snippet id selector is use.Then you can append or create new text

Here is a sample code snippet

```js
var name = prompt('Whats your name traveler');
if (name !== null && name !== '') {
  document.getElementById('para').textContent = 'Hello ' + name
}
```

```html
<p id='para'></p>
```

Comment: I think `if(name)` is enough to validate . instead of `if (name !== null && name !== '')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = prompt('Whats your name traveler');

if(name !== null)
{
 document.getElementById(h).innerHTML
 =name+"Other text";}

<p id="h"></>
```